# How can I use checkbox selected values in Django query parameters?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a webapp and its works in the manner that when users selects values from a checkbox, its description is displayed. I am currently calling a function which in turn will call another function, I am doing so as I want to use GET instead of POST because since there is no server side alteration hence GET is better instead of POST. How can I achieve this using a single function using GET and query parameters ? Below is my code.

Here is my **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^view_task_description/$', views.view_task_description, name='view_task_description'),
url(r'^view_task_description/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_task_description, name="get_task_description"),
```

Here is my **views.py**:

```
@login_required
def view_task_description(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_description = GetTaskDescription(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if task_description.is_valid():
            obj = GetTaskDescription.get_task_description(task_description)
            return redirect('get_task_description', pk=obj[0].pk)
    return render(request, 'todoapp/select_task_description.html', context={'view_tasks': GetTaskDescription(user=request.user)})


@login_required
def get_task_description(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'todoapp/task_desc.html', context={'description': obj.description})
```

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
class GetTaskDescription(forms.Form):

    get_tasks = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Task.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(GetTaskDescription, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['get_tasks'].queryset = self.user.task_set.all()

    def get_task_description(self):
        tasks = self.cleaned_data['get_tasks']
        return tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

Change source of form data in the view:

`task_description = GetTaskDescription(data=request.GET, user=request.user)`